# How could I add a while loop into my code when there's already if statements

Tags: java

Have seen other posts, but I don't know when to enter the while loop or for loop for my program run until it meets conditions, which is enter a number between 1 and 20 and the run the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultiplicationTable {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number, total;

    System.out.println("Please enter an integer from 1 to 20:");            
    number = scanner.nextInt(); 

        if (number >= 21){  
        System.out.println("Your integer must be between 1 and 20.");
        }
        else if ( number <= 0){
        System.out.println("Your integer must be between 1 and 20.");
        }
        else {    
        for(int i = 1; i<=20; i++){
            total = number * i;
            System.out.println(i + " X " + number + " = " + total);
            }

        }

  }

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Put a while loop around the scanner input

```
while(number < 0 || number > 20)
{
    number = scanner.nextInt();
    // if statements here
}
```

With this, you will need to initialize number so that you get into the loop

```
int number = -1;
```

Comment: Or a `do`-`while` loop.